# Find the specific GameObject that called a script method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a game object (a menu) that has a script attached to it. One of the methods in that script adds buttons dynamically onto the menu, and another method in the script is called when one of the dynamic buttons is pressed. I want to find out which button the user has clicked.

When I try to use something like `this.transform.GetSiblingIndex();` I can look at `this.name` and see that I'm getting the menu object where the script is attached and not the button where I'm calling the method.

Is it possible to find out which button/object called that button-clicked method? Or do I need to restructure my code so that I'm using a script attached to the button instead? Although I'm not sure how that would work if the button is being dynamically generated at runtime. Or perhaps I could try some other way of locating where the click happens on the menu, but other than that I'm at a bit of a loss here, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you have a generic click handler that the buttons call when clicked, you can add `Button sender` as a param and have the button pass itself when calling click.  This is how Microsoft handles event callbacks  `MyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)`, which allows you to type check the sender and cast it to the appropriate type.

Comment: @hijinxbassist refers to [`EventHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler) ;)